# Disappearing of different pictures on hosting

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, plesk

I have more than 50 images on my website. I pull them all with ajax. My problem is it gives 404 not found error after 30 images.
I changed the formats of the images. I reduced the dimensions but in vain... I can access the pictures one by one in the new tab. I couldn't understand what the problem was. I am listing images dynamically. This issue does not exist on localhost. I only get an error when I upload it to the hosting panel.

The technologies I use are available in the tag.

Comment: I suggest using your browsers dev tools and view the network tab and console errors.  Do a sanity check and verify you are really getting a 404 and whether the images really exists or not. Check the server logs as well.  No one can answer this unless you show us some code - as limited amount of code as possible to display the issue.

Comment: @bmiller I can share code but i dont think that its happening bcs of it. because i published same website to another plesk account. There is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can share code but i dont think that its happening bcs of it. because i published same website to another plesk account. There is no problem

I think that, it's the same problem as I had before. if you are requesting images from different domain. This issue can be because of hotlink protection.

if this images in your current domain and as you said. if you can access all images in new tab etc. I have doubt about ddos protection. I changed ddos protection settings in my plesk panel and  problem was gone...  you can uncheck this protection or increase limitation.

> Prevent Ddos attacks with IIS dynamic IP limitation
> Deny IP addresses based on number of simultaneous requests from a unique IP address

you can uncheck this protection or increase limitation. Ask your hosting  provider maybe you don't need this option

Comment: thanks you, i asked hosting company. they said you don't need to use this option. Also which i published website. ıt has not ddos options